# Why do CNN's use ReLU over Sigmoid function?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to map my basic understanding of MLP's to CNN's. Why does a CNN sacrifice all negative inputs with the ReLU over the sigmoid. 
Is it because:

The sigmoid has a range of between zero and 1 which is worse for CNN's than 0 to infinity.

Is it to do with the fact the function only has one horizontal asymptote?

The negative inputs are meaningless? 
Or to speed up computation? [Implied here on this question.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226923/why-do-we-use-relu-in-neural-networks-and-how-do-we-use-it)

Any help is a appreciated.

Comment: https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/reluICML.pdf

Comment: @Sycorax you know how to break that up? that's pretty complex tbh not sure if people will get it

Comment: this question is closely related, and should help to get you started https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330559/why-is-tanh-almost-always-better-than-sigmoid-as-an-activation-function/330885#comment626799_330885 and this one https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101560/tanh-activation-function-vs-sigmoid-activation-function