# Why do people use tanh more often than ReLU in vanilla recurrent neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

For instance, the default activation function of `tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN` is tanh.
My doubt is because tanh activation functions may also cause (like sigmoids) the vanishing gradient problem.

Comment: It's not directly about RNNs but I hope the discussions here will give you some direction: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330559/why-is-tanh-almost-always-better-than-sigmoid-as-an-activation-function

Comment: Yes. But the vanish gradient problem with the sigmoid is very explicit.